# My "Snake" app. is not displaying fully even though there are no compilation errors

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm trying to create a version of the snake game but it is not working correctly. What it is doing now is displaying a black screen without any of the components in the `paintComponent` section. Occasionally it displays my "Game Over" message after a while so something is working but the snake and food are not displaying.

I've tried for hours to look for any logic error but have not been able to find any. If anyone would be able to guide me on what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Below is my code that sets up the board and underneath that is my main class that runs the program. I put the entire code just in case you wanted to run it on your own devices but the important pieces of code have 2 stars surrounding them. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Board2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private int bWidth = 500;
private int bHeight = 500;
private int segmentSize = 10;
private int bodyMax = 2500;
private int randomPos = 29;
private int delay = 140;

private int x[] = new int[bodyMax];
private int y[] = new int[bodyMax]; 

private int bodySize, foodX, foodY;

private boolean leftDirection = false;
private boolean rightDirection = true;
private boolean upDirection = false;
private boolean downDirection = false;
private boolean inGame = true;

private Timer timer;
private Image head;
private Image food;
private Image body;

Board2(){
    addKeyListener(new changeDirection());
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bWidth, bHeight));
    loadImages();
    init();
}

**private void loadImages(){
    ImageIcon headImage = new ImageIcon("Square-Freemason-Symbols-300x300.png");
    head = headImage.getImage();

    ImageIcon foodImage = new ImageIcon("Square-Freemason-Symbols-300x300.png");
    food = foodImage.getImage();

    ImageIcon bodyImage = new ImageIcon("Flat1.jpg");
    body = bodyImage.getImage();
}**

private void init(){
    bodySize = 3;

    for(int z = 0; z < bodySize; z++){
        x[z] = 50 - z * 10;
        y[z] = 50;
    }

    findFood();

    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}

**private void doDrawing(Graphics g){
    if(inGame){
        g.drawImage(food, foodX, foodY, this);

        for(int z = 0; z < bodySize; z++){
            if(z == 0){
                g.drawImage(head, x[z], y[z], this);
            } else {
                g.drawImage(body, x[z], y[z], this);
            }
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    } else {
        gameOver(g);
    }
}**

private void gameOver(Graphics g){
    String msg = "Game Over";
    Font small = new Font("Helvetiva", Font.BOLD, 14);
    FontMetrics metr = getFontMetrics(small);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(small);
    g.drawString(msg, (bWidth - metr.stringWidth(msg)/2), bHeight/2);
}

private void findFood(){
    int r = (int) Math.random() * randomPos;
    foodX = r * segmentSize;

    int s = (int) Math.random() * randomPos;
    foodY = s * segmentSize;
}

private void checkFood(){
    if(x[0] == foodX && y[0] == foodY){
        bodySize += 3;
        findFood();
    }
}

private void checkCollision(){
    for(int z = bodySize; z > 0; z--){
        if(z > 4 && x[0] == x[z] && y[0] == y[z]){
            inGame = false;
        }
    }
    if(x[0] > bWidth){
        inGame = false;
    }
    if(x[0] < 0){
        inGame = false;
    }
    if(y[0] >bHeight){
        inGame = false;
    }
    if(y[0] < 0){
        inGame = false;
    }
}

private void Move(){
    for(int z = bodySize; z > 0; z--){
        x[z] = x[z - 1];
        y[z] = y[z - 1];
    }
    if(leftDirection){
        x[0] -= segmentSize;
    }
    if(rightDirection){
        x[0] += segmentSize;
    }
    if(upDirection){
        y[0] -= segmentSize;
    }
    if(downDirection){
        y[0] += segmentSize;
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(inGame){
        checkFood();
        checkCollision();
        Move();
    }

}

public class changeDirection extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !rightDirection){
            leftDirection = true;
            upDirection = false;
            downDirection = false;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !leftDirection){
            rightDirection = true;
            upDirection = false;
            downDirection = false;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !downDirection){
            upDirection = true;
            leftDirection = false;
            rightDirection = false;
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !upDirection){
            downDirection = true;
            leftDirection = false;
            rightDirection = false;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
public class SnakeV2 extends JFrame{

SnakeV2(){

    add(new Board2());
    setResizable(false);
    pack();

    setTitle("SnakeV2");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            JFrame ex = new SnakeV2();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: *"My “Snake” applet is not displaying fully even though there are no compilation errors"*  Note:  Code that generates no compile errors or warnings can still have many bugs that are only revealed at run-time.

Comment: *"I've tried for hours to look for any logic error..."*  You need to hone your debugging skills.  For starters, change `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { ..` to `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("KeyEvent: " + e); ..` and report back on the output when the relevant keys are pressed..